# GET http://js:port/socket.io/1/ 404 not found

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

Socket.io is having issues connecting up.

**This is my Server code:**

```
function chatserver(){

var express = require('express'),

app = express(),

server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),function(){

        console.log('Express server listening on port '+ app.get('port'));
    });
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    users = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('new user', function(data, callback){
        if (data in users){
            callback(false);
        } else{
            callback(true);
            socket.nickname = data;
            users[socket.nickname] = socket;
            updateNicknames();
        }
    });

    function updateNicknames(){
        io.sockets.emit('usernames', Object.keys(users));
    }

    socket.on('send message', function(data, callback){
        var msg = data.trim();
        console.log('after trimming message is: ' + msg);
        if(msg.substr(0,3) === '/w '){
            msg = msg.substr(3);
            var ind = msg.indexOf(' ');
            if(ind !== -1){
                var name = msg.substring(0, ind);
                var msg = msg.substring(ind + 1);
                if(name in users){
                    users[name].emit('whisper', {msg: msg, nick: socket.nickname});
                    console.log('message sent is: ' + msg);
                    console.log('Whisper!');
                } else{
                    callback('Error!  Enter a valid user.');
                }
            } else{
                callback('Error!  Please enter a message for your whisper.');
            }
        } else{
            io.sockets.emit('new message', {msg: msg, nick: socket.nickname});
        }
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
        if(!socket.nickname) return;
        delete users[socket.nickname];
        updateNicknames();
    });
});
}
```

My HTML script code:

```
jQuery(function($){

        var socket = io.connect('js/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js');

        var $nickForm = $('#setNick');
        var $nickError = $('#nickError');
        var $nickBox = $('#nickname');
        var $users = $('#users');
        var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
        var $messageBox = $('#message');
        var $chat = $('#chat');

        $nickForm.submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('new user', $nickBox.val(), function(data){
                if(data){
                    $('#nickWrap').hide();
                    $('#contentWrap').show();
                } else{
                    $nickError.html('That username is already taken!  Try again.');
                }
            });
            $nickBox.val('');
        });

        socket.on('usernames', function(data){
            var html = '';
            for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                html += data[i] + '<br/>'
            }
            $users.html(html);
        });

        $messageForm.submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val(), function(data){
                $chat.append('<span class="error">' + data + "</span><br/>");
            });
            $messageBox.val('');
        });

        socket.on('new message', function(data){
            $chat.append('<span class="msg"><b>' + data.nick + ': </b>' + data.msg + "</span><br/>");
        });

        socket.on('whisper', function(data){
            $chat.append('<span class="whisper"><b>' + data.nick + ': </b>' + data.msg + "</span><br/>");
        });
    });
```

When I load up the website at first it's OK. But as soon as I click the chat box, in inspect elements/console I get to see `"GET http://'js':5001/socket.io/1/?.."` error appear. Please advise.

Comment: Try changing the clientside connect to `io.connect(document.location.hostname)`

Answer (score 3):

In server code, change this:

```
server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(port),

io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
```

to

```
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

If you are in http server not express.io server, use this:

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
   console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: interesting. the error is still here but the console output is "express server listening on port undefined". Any idea why?

Comment: Works fine for me tanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is client Jquery script.

> var socket = io.connect('js/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js');

It is not the proper way to server `socket.io.js` to client.
You need to change it to `http://<ip/domain>:<port>/socket.io/socket.io.js`

If `Socket.io` Server listens properly to your `HTTP` server, it will automatically serve the client file to via `http://<ip/domain>:<port>/socket.io/socket.io.js`. You don't need to find it or copy in public accessible folder as `resources/js/socket.io.js` & serve it manually.

**Code sample** 
[Express 3.x](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) -
Express 3 requires that you instantiate a http.Server to attach `socket.io` to first

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http');
//make sure you keep this order
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//... 

server.listen(8000);
```

Happy Coding :)